# Is there a convenient way to swap two words that aren't adjacent?

Tags: text-editing, selection

I've recently been editing some source code where I often want to swap elements in an array that spans multiple lines.

Doing this manually is quite tedious, moving the cursor between both locations and copy-pasting twice.

It's possible to write a utility that does this - which would be much faster than copy-pasting between two locations (either with a single mouse drag, or marking two locations with the cursor).

However for all I know this may already exist.

Does Emacs provide a convenient way to do this, or is there a package this supports this feature?

Comment: Just read about https://github.com/kwrooijen/transpose-mark today. This may be something to look at.

Answer (score 11):

Function transpose-words can do that.

- Set a mark at one word (C-SPC).
- Move the cursor to the other word.
- C-0 M-t

Enjoy!